# Call Api Service from HomeController

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call a method in my Api Service:

```
public IQueryable Get(int UserId){

     return UsersRepository.SelectAll().Where(ig => ig.Id == UserId);

}
```

from my HomeController:

```
UsersService.Get(UserId);
```

but I get this error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Api.Services.UsersService.Get(int)'`

What am I doing wrong? Here is my UserService:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Data.Repositories;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Model;

namespace CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Api.Services
{
    public class UsersService
    {
        protected readonly IUsersRepository UsersRepository;

        public UsersService(IUsersRepository userRespository)
        {
            UsersRepository = userRespository;
        }

        public IQueryable Get(int UserId)
        {
            return UsersRepository.SelectAll().Where(ig => ig.Id == UserId);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Home Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Model;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Api.Services;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Data.Repositories;

namespace CTHRC.Roti.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/account/login");
            }
            int UserId = 1;
            UsersService.Get(UserId);
            return View();

        }

    }
}
```

here is my IUsersRespository:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Model;

namespace CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Data.Repositories
{
    public interface IUsersRepository : IRepository<Users>
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call an instance method like a static method.
You have to instansiate `UsersService` in order to access the `Get` method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/account/login");
        }

        int UserId = 1;

        var service = new UsersService(userRepository);
        service.Get(UserId);

        return View();

    }
  }
```

Comment: though looks like OP is using some form of DI container, so best to use that to fetch the `UserService` instance. e.g. `var service = kernel.Get<UserService>()` (or some facsimile)

Comment: This gives me another error....The name 'userRepository' does not exist in current context

Comment: I had no example of the OP using a DI container, so i preferred to leave it clear and simple. If he uses one, he can instansiate it anyway he desires

Comment: the `userRepository` was just an example, as `UsersService` needs to receive a `IUserRepository` in its constructor. Do you use any Dependency Injection container?

Comment: `kernel.Get<UserService>()` gives me an error 'The name kernel' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: I dont know what a Dependency Injection container is

Comment: @user3723240 These are just examples. How do you create an instance of `IUserRepository` interface?

Comment: I added my IUsersRepository to my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56372/discussion-between-user3723240-and-yuval-itzchakov).